# Function doesn't work when form embedded in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Why the below code doesn't work in excel sheet? This code is covert an excel file to text file based on user selection, the selection can be export full excel sheet or selected range and user also can choose delimiter of the text file. I've tested this code in excel sheet form and it works well however if change the userform to embedded in excel sheet, it doesn't work completely. It does generate text file but all value are blank, any idea ?

```
Public Sub ExportToTextFile(FName As String, SourceFile As String, _
Sep As String, SelectionOnly As Boolean, _
AppendData As Boolean)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim StartCol As Integer
Dim EndCol As Integer
Dim CellValue As String

 StarRange = StrCol & StrRow
 EndRange = EndCols & endrows


 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 On Error GoTo EndMacro:
 FNum = FreeFile
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(SourceFile)
 Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")


If SelectionOnly = True Then
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
    StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
    EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
End With
Else

With ActiveSheet.Range(StarRange & ":" & EndRange)

    StartRow = .Cells(1).Row
    StartCol = .Cells(1).Column
    EndRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    EndCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
End With
End If

If AppendData = True Then
Open FName For Append Access Write As #FNum
Else
Open FName For Output Access Write As #FNum
End If
 For RowNdx = StartRow To EndRow
WholeLine = ""
For ColNdx = StartCol To EndCol
    If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
        CellValue = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    Else
       CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
    End If
    WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
Next ColNdx
WholeLine = Left(WholeLine, Len(WholeLine) - Len(Sep))
Print #FNum, WholeLine
Next RowNdx

EndMacro:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close #FNum
MsgBox "Completed.", vbInformation
 ActiveWorkbook.Close
 End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet` can be dangerous if your calling it from some other location.  My guess is that `ActiveSheet` is referencing something other than what you want and the range on that sheet is blank.  Also, you define ws as sheet1 but never actually use it from what I can tell.

Comment: How to modify it ? I guess ActiveSheet refer to something other than what I want.

Comment: I can confirmed it refer to the excel sheet which I want by adding MsgBox "The name of the active sheet is " & ActiveSheet.Name and range on the sheet not a blank value.

Comment: Found out the root cause. The code doesn't refer to excel sheet which I want to. It always refer to excel sheet which embedded form was created. How can I change the code so it can refer to the correct excel sheet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim StartCol As Integer
Dim EndCol As Integer
Dim CellValue As String

 StarRange = StrCol & StrRow
 EndRange = EndCols & endrows
```

I suspect you have some typos in your variable names. Is it `StartRow` or `StrRow`, for example?

Without using a fine-toothed comb to do your debugging for you, I would highly recommend that you always use

```
Option Explicit
```

at the start of every module. This tells VBA "don't let me use any variables I did not explicitly declare" - which in practice means (most of the time) "warn me if I misspelled a variable".

I also noticed that you set a variable `ws` in the line

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Then proceed not to use it. Portland Runner posted a good suggestion for how to make use of such a variable - although without seeing the rest of your code / form, it's not clear if that does a better job for you. Typically "ActiveSheet" is a bad idea - it is usually a relic from recording a macro, but not the most efficient or portable thing to do.

It looks like you took code from a couple of different places and repurposed it. I recommend that you go through line by line and make sure that every line is needed, and does what you want.

Finally, as part of the debugging process I would put a breakpoint (F9) in the line

```
WholeLine = ""
```

then step through to see whether lines are being formed as you think they are (input range is right, formatting is right, and line is written correctly). My suspicion lies with the way you define your input range. Are `StartRow`, `StartCol` etc. actually what you want them to be?

Finally (and possible most importantly) in the lines

```
For ColNdx = StartCol To EndCol
    If Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
        CellValue = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    Else
       CellValue = Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
    End If
    WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
Next ColNdx
```

You refer to `Cells` - but don't reference the workbook / sheet that these cells belong to. I suspect that VBA is referencing a difference sheet than you intended. Again - if you properly create the `ws` variable, then these lines should be changed to

```
For ColNdx = StartCol To EndCol
    If ws.Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = "" Then
        CellValue = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    Else
       CellValue = ws,Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value
    End If
    WholeLine = WholeLine & CellValue & Sep
Next ColNdx
```

and that may well solve your problem.